# Inout not working with SubClass object throws Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument

Tags: swift, arkit, inout

I have two block of codes

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
  // BLOCK 1 Which is not working 
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    var plane = Plane(with: planeAnchor) //IT IS SUBCLASS OF SCNNode
    var geo = plane.geometry
    plane.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)

    update(&plane, withGeometry: plane.geo, type: .static)

   //Up here Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'Plane' to 'SCNNode' requires a temporary

    node.addChildNode(plane)

   // BLOCK 2 Which is working 


    let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
    let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
    let plane1 = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

    plane1.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

    var planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane1)

    let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
    let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
    let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
    planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

    update(&planeNode, withGeometry: plane1, type: .static)
    // WORKING FINE

    node.addChildNode(planeNode)

    self.planes[anchor.identifier] = plane

}
```

**BLOCK1**

I have subclass  `class Plane: SCNNode`  when I try to pass it's object to function which required `inout` it shows me error

> Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'Plane' to 'SCNNode' requires a temporary

While if I remove subclass then it is working fine

Why this is it swift bug or I am missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Plane class is initialized with "init(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor)" even it is declared as SCNNode class it returns a different instance than a pure SCNNode as in the Block 2.

I'm not an expert on the mutation subject but think there is an interesting document in Apple blogs [The Role of Mutation in Safety](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)

Not really sure but since a class is by nature mutable you probably can move the update function to the Plane class as a (test) solution

Comment: Thanks for answer but Not This is not true !!

Comment: Thanks, as I said I’m not an expert so I should find time to try myself. But what part is not true? Have you read the link?

Comment: **Since the Plane class is initialized with "init(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor)" even it is declared as SCNNode class it returns a different instance than a pure SCNNode as in the Block 2.**  both is same , if you create subclass of some other class it will never change in behaviour it will be same like create super class instance

Comment: Hey Jose I apologies   , Yes You are right for `inout`  It requires the same class object that has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

### Inout will not work with `Subclass`

Here is example

```
class SuperClass {
    var name = "Prashant"

}

class TestObject:SuperClass {
}


func updateTemp ( object:inout SuperClass) {
    object.name = "P.T"
}
```

Now when you create `TestObject` object which is subclass of `SuperClass` it will not allow to do so.

```
var obj  = TestObject()
self.updateTemp(object: &obj) // Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'TestObject' to 'SuperClass' requires a temporary
print(obj.name)
```

### **How to fix this**

Three ways

1)     create object with    `var obj:SuperClass  = TestObject()`

2)    This actually don't required to be `inout` as class is reference type

3) Create Generic function like it  (Generic is great !! )

```
func updateTemp<T:SuperClass> ( object:inout T) {
    object.name = "P.T"
}
```

Hope it is helpful to someone